# combine two regular expression into one

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two regular expression. How can I convert them into one:

```
str = str.replace(/(\s\(\d+\)|exception\s*\:*)/gi, "<br /><br />$1");
str = str.replace(/(exception\s+No\.\s*\d\:)/gi,"<br /><br />$1");
```

I want to convert them into one regular expression. How can i do it?

thanks in advance

Comment: Analyze both and refactor?

Comment: no just convert them into one....

Comment: IMO, the `&nbsp` will make them impossible to merge.

Comment: now..i have remove the &nbsp..now is it possible...if than what is the solution..

Comment: @user1522525 Then, just put a logical OR (i.e. `|`) between your two regexes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not an optimized regexp but a very simple solution is to combine your regexps with a `|`:

```
str = str.replace(/((?:\s\(\d+\)|exception\s*\:*)|exception\s+No\.\s*\d\:)/gi, "<br /><br />$1");
```