# Can these two regular expressions (match and replace) be combined into a single operation?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm extracting a four-part version number from a filename and converting it to a SemVer-compliant version.

1. Filename: `MyApp v2020.8.3.1.exe`
2. SemVer: `2020.8.3-r1`

I've been successful at doing this using two steps:

```
sVersion = Regex.Match("MyApp v2020.8.3.1.exe", "[A-Za-z ]|\.[A-Za-z]").Value
oSemver = New Regex("\.(?=[^\.]+$)")
sSemVer = oSemver.Replace(sVersion, "-r")
```

This produces the desired SemVer-compliant version.

However, for the sake of brevity, I'd like to combine these two steps into a single operation.

I tried several variations on a couple of Q&As I found:

- [combine two regular expression into one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15921877)
- [Combining these two Regular Expressions into one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2145651)

...but I didn't have much luck.

For example:

`([A-Za-z ]|\.[A-Za-z])|(\.(?=[^\.]+$))` replaced with `$2` produces only the four-part version number `2020.8.3.1`.

Is this possible, given the constraints I'm working with?

**--EDIT--**

I only need a SemVer-compliant version number, not a new filename. In other words, I need to strip off all the extraneous characters (in this case `MyApp v` and `.exe`) and replace the final `.` in the four-part version number with `-r`.

Comment: What is the actual output here... Do you want a new filename, or just a version? are the input versions always 4 parts ? Maybe you can give a bunch of inputs and outputs.

Comment: No, not a new filename. Just a version. See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand what you want (and i am not sure i do)

**Update**

```
var input = "MyApp v2020.8.3.1.exe";
var m = Regex.Match(input, @"(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)");
var result = $"{m.Groups[1]}.{m.Groups[2]}.{m.Groups[3]}-r{m.Groups[4]}";
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
2020.8.3-r1
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dkmyPB)

or you could just use `(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.(\d+)` which would result in 2 groups

---

**Original**

```
var input = "MyApp v2020.8.3.1.exe";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)", "$1.$2.$3-r$4");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
MyApp v2020.8.3-r1.exe
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mR7m3Y)

Comment: Close, but not quite. I need to extract `2020.8.3.1` from the filename and convert it to `2020.8.3-r1`. I only need the SemVer-compliant version, not a new filename.

Comment: Beauteous! Now why didn't I think of that?

Comment: I recently was able to push through the ceiling that was blocking me from figuring out the whole regular expressions paradigm. It's all starting to come clear to me now, and stuff like this really helps. Thanks much :-)

Comment: @InteXX all good, I was hiding behind the door when they were handing out regular expression skills.

Comment: Nifty neato :-)

Comment: FYI I tuned up your 2-group expression a little bit. I like that one. That's the one I'm going to use.